# How to set the sub-account value from code to Dimension selector

Tags: acumatica

In acumatica requisition screen, we saw that even if the sub-account doesnt exists, it creates it when the user enters a new value. How can we set new values to the dimension selector using code?

The subid in the backend is an integer, so we are not sure how to handle.

Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Account and the Sub-Account fields work in a way similar to the PXSelectorAttribute with the SubstituteKey property set. The Account and the Sub-Account fields are usually decorated with the AccountAttribute and the SubAccountAttribute. In their constructors the AccountAttribute and the SubAccountAttribute always initialize an instance of the PXDimensionSelectorAttribute, which subscribes to FieldUpdating and FieldSelecting handlers to transform the field value between the internal (integer) and external (string) presentation.

To set value for Account or Sub-Account field, you should raise FieldUpdating handler with external (string) value passed as second `ref` parameter:

```
public class RQRequisitionEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<RQRequisitionEntry>
{
    public PXAction<RQRequisition> AddLine;
    [PXButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Add Line")]
    protected void addLine()
    {
        PXCache cache = Base.Lines.Cache;

        RQRequisitionLine line = Base.Lines.Insert();
        line.InventoryID = 691;
        line = Base.Lines.Update(line);

        object acctID = "10100";
        cache.RaiseFieldUpdating<RQRequisitionLine.expenseAcctID>(line, ref acctID);
        line.ExpenseAcctID = (int?)acctID;

        object subID = "CONFIN";
        cache.RaiseFieldUpdating<RQRequisitionLine.expenseSubID>(line, ref subID);
        line.ExpenseSubID = (int?)subID;

        Base.Lines.Update(line);
    }
}
```

If there is no sub-account value in database, the SubAccountAttribute generates a temporary negative integer value. New sub-account value will be saved in database by the SubAccountAttribute during execution of the Persist() method.